# Using ～なくなった vs. ～ない

Tags: negation

> 情報の真偽を確かめるまで帰れなくなった

What does なくなった add? I'm parsing なくなった　as なくなる　or the negative form of なる　to become. So loosely it sounds like, "you will lose the ability to leave"。

> 情報の真偽を確かめるまで帰れない

Is this the same or correct when just using ～ない, not allowed to leave？

Comment: The verb なる made it change. The first sentence said he was able to do it, but not anymore now. The second one just says not able to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb 「なる」, which is a key verb in the language, always describes a change of state as in:

・A turns into B.

・A becomes more/less (adjective).

・Situation A changes to situation B.

> 「情報{じょうほう}の真偽{しんぎ}を確{たし}かめるまで帰{かえ}れなく**なった**。」

This sentence talks about a (fairly recent) change of state as below:

**Old state**: One was free to leave or was about to leave.

*Something happens that changes all that*.  ← Perhaps a new piece of information has come in.

**Present state**: One cannot leave until the authenticity of the information has been verified.

Old state （帰れた）⇒⇒ New state （帰れなくなった）

「帰れなくなった」＝「帰れる」+「ない」+「なる」 in the past tense

Thus your first sentence means something along the lines of:

> "It has (just) become impossible for me/us to leave until the authenticity of the information has been verified."

Your second sentence:

> 「情報の真偽を確かめるまで帰れない。」

says nothing about a change of state (like your first sentence does).  It just means:

> "One cannot leave until the authenticity of the information has been verified."

Comment: if I want to say the same but in the affirmative, should I say 「情報の真偽を確かめるまで帰るようになった」?

Comment: @Felipe To mean "It has become possible to leave (only) after / if the authenticity of the information has been verified", it'd be 「情報の真偽を確かめ｛たら/れば｝帰れるようになった」... とか・・